# JQ filter and output format

Tags: jq

For an input below:

```
[{
  "commit": {
    "author": {
      "name": "Stephen Dolan",
      "email": "mu@netsoc.tcd.ie",
      "date": "2013-06-22T16:30:59Z"
    },
    "committer": {
      "name": "Stephen Dolan",
      "email": "mu@netsoc.tcd.ie",
      "date": "2013-06-22T16:30:59Z"
    },
    "message": "Merge pull request #162 from stedolan/utf8-fixes\n\nUtf8 fixes. Closes #161"
    "url":"https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits/d25341478381063d1c76e81b3a52e0592a7c997f"    
  },
  {
    ...
  }
}]
```

How can JQ generate a delimited string from different objects as shown below?

```
"Stephen Dolan",  "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits/d25341478381063d1c76e81b3a52e0592a7c997f",  "2013-06-22T16:30:59Z"
```

Comment: new to jq here.  I followed the examples, but could not figure out on how to format output

Answer (score 5):

Collect the fields you want in an array and use `@csv` to convert to a CSV row.  Make sure you get the raw output.

```
jq -r '.[] | [ .commit.author.name, .commit.url, .commit.author.date ] | @csv' input.json
```